# java script Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code has a problem but I can't find the mistake . please help to correct this .

```
document.write('

<div>
<a href=http://www.socialsignal.ir style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>سوشیال سیگنال</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://www.seoro.ir style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>سئو</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://hiappleid.com/ style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>خرید اپل ایدی</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://zheek.ir/ style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>طراحی وب سایت</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://yamonji.com/ style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>امام زمان</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://deepenglish.ir/ style=\'\\padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;\'\\ target=\'\\_blank\'\\>یادگیری زبان انگلیسی</a>&nbsp;       
</div>
      ');
```

Comment: What makes you so sure there is something wrong with it? Any kind of error message that might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems is here. string within `''` don't support mulitline, so you need to concatenate each line in your code.

Just use [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and write your string without `\` for special symbols.

```js
document.write(`

<div>
<a href=http://www.socialsignal.ir style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>سوشیال سیگنال</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://www.seoro.ir style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>سئو</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://hiappleid.com/ style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>خرید اپل ایدی</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://zheek.ir/ style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>طراحی وب سایت</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://yamonji.com/ style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>امام زمان</a>&nbsp;

<a href=http://deepenglish.ir/ style='padding:5px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #555;background-color:#eee;border-radius:5px;color: #000;display:-webkit-inline-box;z-index:50;' target='_blank'>یادگیری زبان انگلیسی</a>&nbsp;       
</div>`);
```